# Bad indentation on iamRoleStatements yaml serverless

Tags: function, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I'm creating a Role Statement for my Lambda functions inside of serverless.yml file, but i keep getting this error

"bad indentation of a mapping entry"

And this is how the file looks like:

```
iamRoleStatements: 
    - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
        - "sns:Publish"
    Resource: "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
        - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
    Resource: "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:888186450240:*"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
iamRoleStatements: 
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sns:Publish"
      Resource: "arn:aws:sns:*:*:*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
      Resource: "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:888186450240:*"
```

`iamRoleStatements` is an array of objects